# In what situations is shutdown/close done in the foreground or background?

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll

I'm doing an abortive close on a socket at the server end using:

```
struct linger so_linger;
so_linger.l_onoff = 1;
so_linger.l_linger = 0;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &so_linger, socklen_t)sizeof(so_linger));

shutdown(s, SHUT_WR);
close(s);
```

Where `s` is the socket I'm closing.

It works, but I've encountered a problem sometimes and it appears to affect some servers and not others.  Some are running on Ubuntu, and some on CoreOS.  It works fine on CoreOS.

On Ubuntu, I'm getting an event from epoll_wait related to the socket despite having close called.

I assumed this would happen immediately.  But I suppose that may not be the case if you're using non-blocking I/O.

It essentially means I get events in epoll_wait that have an ev.data.ptr value set that points to something that has been destroyed.

So, the question is, is this true? a half close won't remove the event descriptor from epoll and shutdown will not be synchronous with non-blocking i/o?

Therefore if I no longer want the events I should in fact remove the descriptor manually with EPOLL_CTL_DEL?

Comment: You're sending a FIN and then an RST. Why?

Comment: @EJP - You mean this isn't doing an abortive close?  it seems to work though.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the socket does clear it out from the epoll set. But there is a caveat. Referring to [epoll man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)
:

```
> Q6  Will closing a file descriptor cause it to be removed from all
           epoll sets automatically?

   A6  Yes, but be aware of the following point.  A file descriptor is a
       reference to an open file description (see open(2)).  Whenever a
       file descriptor is duplicated via dup(2), dup2(2), fcntl(2)
       F_DUPFD, or fork(2), a new file descriptor referring to the same
       open file description is created.  An open file description
       continues to exist until all file descriptors referring to it
       have been closed.  A file descriptor is removed from an epoll set
       only after all the file descriptors referring to the underlying
       open file description have been closed (or before if the file
       descriptor is explicitly removed using epoll_ctl(2)
       EPOLL_CTL_DEL).This means that even after a file descriptor
       that is part of an epoll set has been closed, events may be
       reported for that file descriptor if other file descriptors
       referring to the same underlying file description remain open.
```

So, there is possibility of events reported on the socket for which `close` was called. Not sure if your could be that case for your test works fine on certain platforms. And certainly, I don't think it has to do with asynchronous I/O.